# Display attachment as image rather than link in custom list form

Tags: list, form, custom

I am making a custom list form where the user will input texts and can upload images as attachments. This images will serve as an icon next to the inputted text in the allitems.aspx. How can I make the attachment be viewable as image rather than a link? Any inputs will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation, but for me it was one time activity. Will go ahead and give solution

1. Once we had image attachment in sharepoint list, we opened all those attachment in explorer view and stored them in Picture library.
2. Also created custom column of type Hyperlink and selected type picture in a original list. Updated thumbnail URL for each item from respective image from picture library.
3. Finally we get that thumbnail against each item. Use of picture library is to have thumbnail size images of attachments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint 2013 farm and want to customize the default list forms (Display/New/Edit forms), you can use `Client Side Rendering (CSR)`. It allows you to define your custom rendering in javascript.

There is a nice article on MSDN regarding CSR implementation. Kindly follow along.
[MSDN article on CSR](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)